# How to close pop up windows in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have two scenes - login prompt and Main screen. The openLoginPrompt() function opens the login prompt. Then I call the handleLogin() function which tries to authenticate a user. When login is successful I would like to close the login prompt and return to the Main screen. However if I don't set primaryStage as static primaryStage seems to be null when the handleLogin() function is called. Why does this happen and is there a better alternative to close the stage?

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chatapplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author babaji
 */
public class Controller {


private static Stage primaryStage;

@FXML
private Button openLoginPrompt;
@FXML
private Button login;
@FXML
private TextField username;
@FXML
private PasswordField password;
@FXML
private Label loginMessage;
@FXML
private AnchorPane loginPrompt;

@FXML
private void openLoginPrompt() {
    try {
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(ChatApplication.class.getResource("LoginPrompt.fxml"));
        AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML 
private void handleLogin() {
    Database dbObj = new Database();
    Connection conn = dbObj.connectToDb("chat");
    String uname = username.getText();
    String psswd = password.getText();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name=? AND password=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, uname);
        ps.setString(2, psswd);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int count = 0;
    try {
        if(rs != null) while(rs.next()) count++;
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        count = 0;

    }
    if(count == 1) {
        System.out.println("Successfully Logged in");
        /*This is where the problem Lies. If I dont't set primaryStage as
        static, primaryStage returns null. Why does this happen and is there
        some other way to close the window?s
        */
        if(primaryStage != null) primaryStage.close();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Failed to login.");
        loginMessage.setText("Incorrect username or password");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the controller for both LoginPrompt.fxml and MainScreen.fxml

Comment: `primaryStage` is only ever set in the instance created for `MainScreen.fxml` though.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative way to open a pop up window without using the same controller class?

Comment: Use a separate controller class. Define a `BooleanProperty loggedIn` in that class and observe it from the main controller when you open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two controller instances, one for `LoginPrompt.fxml` and one for another FXML you haven't shown (let's call it the "main" fxml). `openLoginPrompt` is called on the "main" instance, and initializes `primaryStage`, and loads `LoginPrompt.fxml`. When you load the FXML, the `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance of the controller, which doesn't have `primaryStage` initialized (assuming it's not `static`); so when `handleLogin()` is invoked on the `LoginPrompt.fxml` controller, it is `null`.

It's a really bad idea to use the same controller class for two different FXML files, as it leads to all sorts of confusing scenarios such as this, where different fields are initialized in different instances of the class. You should use a different controller class for each FXML file.

In this case, you could define a `LoginController` class. Edit `LoginPrompt.fxml` to use this controller class instead. You can expose various properties from that class and observe them from the main controller when you open the login window:

```
public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Label loginMessage ;

    private final BooleanProperty loggedIn = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public BooleanProperty loggedInProperty() {
        return loggedIn ;
    }

    public final boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedInProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        loggedInProperty().set(loggedIn);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLogin() {
        // existing code you had in the previous version...
        if (count == 1) {
            System.out.println("Successfully logged in");
            setLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to login.");
            loginMessage.setText("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }   

}
```

And then in your main controller you do

```
@FXML
private void openLoginPrompt() {
    try {
        Stage loginStage = new Stage();
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(ChatApplication.class.getResource("LoginPrompt.fxml"));
        AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        LoginController loginController = loader.getController();
        loginController.loggedInProperty().addListener((obs, wasLoggedIn, isNowLoggedIn) -> {
            if (isNowLoggedIn) {
                loginStage.hide();
            }
        });

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        loginStage.setScene(scene);
        loginStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is no need to make the `Stage` a field with this version.

I should also mention there's a "quick and dirty" way to close the stage directly from the `LoginController`:

```
loginMessage.getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

which would avoid needing the property and even getting a reference to the `LoginController` from the main controller. However, you often have situations where you may need data from one controller in another, and the first technique is a more generally useful approach.